# How do I enable Microsoft SQL account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

> Cannot connect to *****\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user '*****\lenovo'. Reason: The account is disabled. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18470)

Comment: [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 5):

1. Log in to 'SQL Server Management Studio', using Windows
   Authentication.
2. Navigate to to 'SQL Server Management Studio' ->
   Server -> Security -> Logins->. In below screenshot,
   login disabled is 'test' [as given here](https://support.pitneybowes.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka280000000PKPb&feoid=00N800000058ndl&refid=0EM80000000jfKG)
3. Right-click on the affected Login (User) and select Properties.
4. In the Login Properties screen, select Status on the left side.
5. Change the Login option from 'Disabled' to 'Enabled'.
6. Navigate to 'General' Tab and enter new password Click OK.

Alternatively you can use the below script in the query window after logging on using windows credentials.

```
ALTER LOGIN login_in_name ENABLE;
```

Comment: Image link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

First, Go to SSMS > Server > Security > Logins. Then Right-click and select Properties. Next Log in using Windows Authentication to be able to make this change. After that In the Login Properties screen, select Status on the left side. And finally Change the Login option from Disabled to Enabled. Click OK. This should fix the problem.